# How can I make my character jump correctly?

Tags: android, animation, character, collision-detection

I have encountered an issue with my character in my game, MathRunner. I recently implemented collision functionality, and it works quite well. However, I am facing problems with the jump action for my character. Despite programming the jump animation to trigger when the user touches the screen or presses the space bar for personal testing, the character appears to jump visually, but internally, the coordinates of the character do not update correctly.

I have attempted various approaches to resolve this issue, but none have succeeded. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me in ensuring the character jumps correctly by updating its coordinates appropriately.

Another detail worth mentioning is that I am working with the properties of the Rect object to handle collisions. Please don't hesitate to ask if further clarification or additional information is needed. Thank you for your assistance.

This is the code of my character "Brain":

```
package com.example.mathrunner;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;

public class Brain extends AppCompatImageView {

    private MyAnimationDrawable brainAnimation;
    private int x, y; // Posición del cerebro en la pantalla
    private int velocityY; // Velocidad vertical del cerebro
    private boolean isJumping; // Indica si el cerebro está saltando
    private Book book; // Agrega una referencia al objeto Book
    private int jumpStartY; // Nueva variable global
    private int originalY;
    private int jumpHeight = 100;
    private long jumpAnimationStartTime;

    private Rect brainRect = new Rect();
    private Rect bookRect = new Rect();

    private Handler updateHandler;

    public Brain(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Brain(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Brain(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Inicializar otras propiedades del cerebro
        x = 0; // Establecer la posición inicial en la pantalla
        y = 0;
        velocityY = 0;
        isJumping = false;

        initializeBrainAnimation(); // Inicializar la animación del cerebro (brain)
        updateHandler = new Handler();
        startUpdateLoop();
    }

    private void startUpdateLoop() {
        updateHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Verificar si el cerebro está saltando y actualizar la posición si es necesario
                if (isJumping) {
                    updateBrainPositionDuringAnimation();
                }

                // Repetir el bucle de actualización después de un breve intervalo
                updateHandler.postDelayed(this, 16); // Aproximadamente 60 FPS (1000 ms / 60 frames)
            }
        }, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        // Detener el bucle de actualización
        updateHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
    }

    public void initializeBrainAnimation() {
        int totalFrames = 45;
        int[] frameDurations = new int[totalFrames];
        Drawable[] frames = new Drawable[totalFrames];

        for (int i = 0; i < totalFrames; i++) {
            frameDurations[i] = Math.max(frameDurations[i], 1);
            int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("brain_frame_" + (i + 1), "drawable", getContext().getPackageName());
            frames[i] = getResources().getDrawable(drawableResourceId);
        }

        brainAnimation = new MyAnimationDrawable(frameDurations, frames);
        setImageDrawable(brainAnimation);

        // Iniciar la animación
        startAnimation();
    }

    public boolean isCollidingWithBook(Book book) {
        // Asegúrate de que el objeto Book no sea nulo
        if (book != null) {
            // Obtén los límites (Rect) de las vistas
            this.getHitRect(brainRect);
            book.getHitRect(bookRect);

            // Imprime la altura y el ancho de los Rectángulos
            Log.d("Rectangles", "Brain Rect: Coords=" + brainRect);
            Log.d("Rectangles", "Book Rect: Coords=" + bookRect);

            return Rect.intersects(brainRect, bookRect);
        } else {
            // Si el objeto Book es nulo, asume que no hay colisión
            Log.d("null","Nulo");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void update() {
        // Actualizar la posición del cerebro
        y += velocityY;

        // Simular la gravedad (ajustar según sea necesario)
        velocityY += Constants.GRAVITY;

        // Verificar si el cerebro ha alcanzado el suelo
        if (y > Constants.GROUND_LEVEL) {
            y = Constants.GROUND_LEVEL;
            velocityY = 0;
            isJumping = false;

        }
    }

    public void jump() {
        velocityY = Constants.JUMP_VELOCITY;
        isJumping = true;
        jumpStartY = getBrainY(); // Almacena la posición Y al iniciar el salto

        // Inicia la animación de salto
        startJumpAnimation();
    }


    public void stopJumpAnimation() {
        if (isJumping) {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }

    private void startJumpAnimation() {
        originalY = getBrainY(); // Almacena la posición original del cerebro
        jumpAnimationStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Registra el tiempo de inicio de la animación

        Animation jumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.brain_jump);

        jumpAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // No es necesario iniciar nada aquí
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                y = Constants.GROUND_LEVEL;
                isJumping = false;

                // Luego de que la animación ha finalizado, verifica la colisión
                checkCollisionWithBook();

                // Restablece la posición original del cerebro después del salto
                setBrainY(originalY);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // No es necesario repetir nada aquí
            }
        });

        if (isJumping) {
            jumpAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // No es necesario iniciar nada aquí
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    y = Constants.GROUND_LEVEL;
                    isJumping = false;

                    // Luego de que la animación ha finalizado, verifica la colisión
                    checkCollisionWithBook();

                    // Restablece la posición original del cerebro después del salto
                    setBrainY(originalY);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // No es necesario repetir nada aquí
                }
            });

            startAnimation(jumpAnimation);
        }
    }


    private void updateBrainPositionDuringAnimation() {
        if (isJumping) {
            // Calcula la nueva posición Y durante la animación de salto
            int newJumpY = jumpStartY - getJumpAnimationOffset();

            // Asegúrate de que no baje más allá del suelo
            y = Math.max(newJumpY, Constants.GROUND_LEVEL);

            // Ajusta el valor de "top" y "bottom" para un salto más grande
            int topValue = Constants.GROUND_LEVEL - getHeight(); // Puedes ajustar esto según tus necesidades
            y = Math.max(y, topValue);

            int jumpHeightIncrease = 50; // Puedes ajustar esto según tus necesidades
            int newBottom = y + getHeight() - jumpHeightIncrease;

            // Establece la nueva posición del cerebro
            setY(y);

            // Actualiza los límites del Rectángulo (Rect) durante la animación de salto
            brainRect.top = y;
            brainRect.bottom = newBottom;

            Log.d("Top: ", "Top" + brainRect.top);
            Log.d("Bottom: ", "Bottom" + brainRect.bottom);
        }
    }



    // Método para obtener un desplazamiento dinámico en la animación de salto
    private int getJumpAnimationOffset() {
        // Obtén la duración total de la animación
        long animationDurationMillis = getJumpAnimationDuration();

        // Calcula el progreso de la animación en un rango de 0 a 1
        float progress = (float) (System.currentTimeMillis() - jumpAnimationStartTime) / animationDurationMillis;

        // Ajusta el rango de progreso según tus necesidades
        // En este ejemplo, uso una función seno para obtener un movimiento más suave
        float offset = (float) Math.sin(progress * Math.PI) * jumpHeight;

        // Devuelve el offset calculado
        return Math.round(offset);
    }

    // Método para obtener la duración total de la animación de salto
    private long getJumpAnimationDuration() {
        // Puedes ajustar esto según la duración real de tu animación
        return 2200; // 2.2 segundos en milisegundos
    }




    private void checkCollisionWithBook() {
        // Verifica la colisión después de que la animación ha finalizado
        if (isCollidingWithBook(book)) {
            Log.d("Collision", "Brain collided with Book!");
            // Agrega aquí cualquier lógica adicional después de la colisión

            // Restablece el valor de "top" después de un salto exitoso
            int topValueAfterSuccessfulJump = Constants.GROUND_LEVEL - getHeight(); // Puedes ajustar esto según tus necesidades
            setBrainY(topValueAfterSuccessfulJump);
        } else {
            Log.d("Collision", "Brain not collided with Book!");
        }
    }

    public void crouch() {
        // Agrega lógica para manejar el agacharse
        // Puedes cambiar la posición, la animación, etc., según tus necesidades
        // Por ejemplo, si tienes una animación específica para cuando se agacha, puedes cambiar la animación aquí

        // Restablecer la posición en Y para simular el agacharse
        y = Constants.GROUND_LEVEL;

        // Cambiar la animación o realizar otras acciones necesarias
        // brainAnimation.setCrouchAnimation(); // Esto es un ejemplo, necesitas definirlo según tus clases y lógica
    }

    // Getter para la posición en X
    public int getBrainX() {
        return x;
    }

    // Setter para la posición en X
    public void setBrainX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    // Getter para la posición en Y
    public int getBrainY() {
        return y;
    }

    // Setter para la posición en Y
    public void setBrainY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    // Método para reducir la velocidad
    public void reduceSpeed() {
        brainAnimation.restartAnimation();
    }

    // Método para iniciar la animación
    private void startAnimation() {
        brainAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the other class that controlls the Activity
GameActivity:

```
package com.example.mathrunner;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Brain brain;
    private Book book;
    private ImageView cloudImageView;
    private int currentCloudIndex = 1;
    private final int totalClouds = 10;
    private final int cloudAnimationDuration = 5000; // 5 seconds
    private final int bookAnimationDuration = 5000;
    private Handler uiHandler; // Agregada declaración de uiHandler
    private Handler speedHandler;
    private int lives = 3;
    private TextView life;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        // Obtén la referencia del nuevo objeto Brain
        brain = findViewById(R.id.brain);
        book = findViewById(R.id.book);
        life= findViewById(R.id.life);
        life.setText(String.valueOf(lives));

        cloudImageView = findViewById(R.id.cloudImageView);
        uiHandler = new Handler(); // Inicializada uiHandler

        // Inicializa la animación del cerebro en la clase Brain
        brain.initializeBrainAnimation();

        // Inicia la animación de desplazamiento de las nubes
        startCloudAnimation();
        // Inicia la animación de desplazamiento del libro
        startBookAnimation();
        speedHandler = new Handler();
        speedHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Ajusta la velocidad utilizando el método de Brain
                brain.reduceSpeed(); // Cambiado a reduceSpeed en Brain
                // Repite después de 10 segundos
                speedHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        }, 0);

        uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Actualizar la posición del cerebro


                // Verificar la colisión con el libro
                if (brain.isCollidingWithBook(book)) {
                    handleCollision(); // Agrega aquí la lógica que desees al producirse la colisión
                }

                // Repite el bucle de juego después de un breve intervalo
                uiHandler.postDelayed(this, 16); // Aproximadamente 60 FPS (1000 ms / 60 frames)
            }
        }, 0);
    }


    private void startBookAnimation() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            private long lastUpdateTime = startTime;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long elapsedTime = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;

                // Actualiza la posición del libro basándote en el tiempo transcurrido y la velocidad deseada
                int displacement = (int) (elapsedTime * Constants.BOOK_SPEED / 500); // velocidad en píxeles por segundo
                float newBookX = book.getX() - displacement;

                // Verifica si el libro se ha movido completamente fuera de la pantalla
                if (newBookX + book.getWidth() < 0) {
                    // Reinicia la posición del libro en el lado derecho de la pantalla
                    newBookX = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                }

                // Establece la nueva posición del libro
                book.setX(newBookX);


                // Ajusta la velocidad del libro con el tiempo
                float elapsedSeconds = (currentTime - startTime) / 500.0f;
                float acceleration = 0.001f; // Puedes ajustar este valor según sea necesario
                float newBookSpeed = Constants.BOOK_SPEED + acceleration * elapsedSeconds;

                // Establece un límite máximo de velocidad para el libro
                float maxBookSpeed = 900f; // Puedes ajustar este valor según sea necesario
                if (newBookSpeed > maxBookSpeed) {
                    newBookSpeed = maxBookSpeed;
                }
                Log.d("pain","Spped Book:" + newBookSpeed);
                // Guarda la nueva velocidad del libro
                Constants.BOOK_SPEED = newBookSpeed;

                // Guarda el tiempo actual para la próxima actualización
                lastUpdateTime = currentTime;

                handler.postDelayed(this, 16); // Aproximadamente 60 FPS (1000 ms / 60 frames)
            }
        });
    }

    // Método para manejar la colisión
    private void handleCollision() {
        Log.d("Collision", "Brain collided with Book!");
        lives--; // Reducir el número de vidas
        life.setText(String.valueOf(lives)); // Actualizar el texto de las vidas
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Finger touched down
                // Start brain jump
                brain.jump();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Finger lifted up
                // Stop jump animation
                brain.stopJumpAnimation();
                break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
            // Tecla de espacio presionada, realiza el salto
            brain.jump();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE) {
            // Tecla de espacio liberada, detén el salto
            brain.stopJumpAnimation();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void startCloudAnimation() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            private int currentDuration = cloudAnimationDuration;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                cloudImageView.setImageResource(getCloudResource(currentCloudIndex));
                Animation cloudTranslationAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(GameActivity.this, R.anim.cloud_translation);
                currentDuration = Math.max(currentDuration, 0);
                cloudTranslationAnimation.setDuration(currentDuration);
                cloudImageView.startAnimation(cloudTranslationAnimation);
                currentCloudIndex = (currentCloudIndex % totalClouds) + 1;

                if (currentDuration >= 500) {
                    currentDuration -= 100;
                }

                handler.postDelayed(this, currentDuration);
            }
        });
    }

    private int getCloudResource(int index) {
        String cloudResourceName = "cloud_" + index;
        return getResources().getIdentifier(cloudResourceName, "drawable", getPackageName());
    }
}
```

And for the last this is the View code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Piso (Fondo azul claro) -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/blueFloorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/blackFloorView"
        android:background="#0a94bf" />

    <!-- Piso (Fondo negro) -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/blackFloorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cloudImageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cloud_1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp" />

    <!-- Cerebro corriendo -->

    <com.example.mathrunner.Brain
        android:id="@+id/brain"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/brain_animation" />

    <com.example.mathrunner.Book
        android:id="@+id/book"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="350dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
        android:src="@drawable/book" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/life"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pain"/>

    <include layout="@layout/lives" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please feel free to ask if you require additional segments of my code. Thank you for your assistance.

I attempted to target and update the animation coordinates, but it appeared ineffective. The coordinates update only once, and afterward, there is no change.

The code is designed to make the character jump, and if the character's "Y" position does not intersect with the book's position, there is no collision, and the character's life is not subtracted.